# import a non-arc library to project

Tags: ios, iphone

I try to import a non-arc library(ASIHTTPRequest) to project.

but it reports arc error.

Is there a way to import a non-arc library to arc project?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for those files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add non arc flag `-fno-objc-arc` in all `ASIHttpRequest` Classes in **ProjectSettings->BuildPhases->Compile Sources**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ARC can be disabled on a ASIHTTPRequest files by file basis with the fno-objc-arc flag.
Set the no-objc-arc flag at path ProjectSettings->BuildPhases->Compile Sources->ASIHTTPRequest .m files.

But it is better to use AFNetworking classes for HTTP request handling now.
AFNetworking is best on now days, whereas ASIHTTPRequest is pretty much dead. Additionally, AFNetworking has dozens of great helper libraries and classes available for handling things like OAuth, Amazon S3, and the like.
AFNetworking also available for ARC support.No need to set flag.